# Radio mode for Windows hostednetwork

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking

I've can successfully start a virtual network through `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`, but I want to be able to set the radio mode the network uses. I have an Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless - AC 3160, which supports 802.11b/g/n/a/ac

Right now `netsh wlan show hostednetwork` shows:

```
Status                 : Started
BSSID                  : xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Radio type             : 802.11n
Channel                : 157
Number of clients      : 0
```

However, I want the radio type to be 802.11g. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Not on channel 157 you can't. That would be 802.11a, which is the 5GHz equivalent of 802.11g (802.11g is 2.4GHz-only). By the way, why would you want to take an AC-capable card and limit it to G rates?

Comment: My 3ds can only connect to 802.11b/g networks, and I am connecting to the internet through my computer's virtual network. Also, is there any way to change the channel then?

Comment: Same problem here, my Raspberry can't connect if the radio is g type. If i am connected to wifi via g, then it uses n and connection succeeds.